# How to make my chrome extension for facebook execute repeatedly, rather than just the first time its loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently making my first chrome extension that makes some HTML changes(filters posts) based on the presence of a particular keyword. This however works just for the first time the page is loaded, and the extension clicked, and not when more stories are loaded. I read that livequery helps, but for some reason that too isn't working, maybe it's depreciated.

Currently, I'm sending a message from the background script to execute the filtering.

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response){
if(message.type=="color-divs"){
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("userContent");
        var blacklist = [
                        "Trump"
                        ]
    for(var i=0; i<blacklist.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<divs.length; j++){
                var ps = divs[j].getElementsByTagName('p');
                var p = ps[0];
                if(p.innerHTML.indexOf(blacklist[i]) != -1 ){
                    alert("lol");
                    var parent = divs[j].parentNode;

                    for(var k = 0; k<parent.childNodes.length; k++){
                        alert(parent.childNodes[k].className);
                        if (parent.childNodes[k].className == "_5x46") {
                            parent.childNodes[k].style.opacity = "0.0";
                        }
                        if (parent.childNodes[k].className == "_5pbx userContent") {
                            parent.childNodes[k].style.backgroundColor = "black";
                        }

                        if (parent.childNodes[k].className == "_3x-2") {
                            parent.childNodes[k].style.opacity = "0.0";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

});

Comment: many questions already cover this.

Comment: See this answer:  [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Using a MutationObserver worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

Try making an event listener. When the new content is loaded, the event is run.